# Live Search With jquery AJAX?

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress, livesearch

How can I create a live search with Jquery AJAX, I used keypress or keyup event to loop query, but if I type 3 characters or more the AJAX will do 3 times or more.

**My form:**

```
<input class="keyword-search" type="text" name="s" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Where do you want to go?">
```

**Here my AJAX:**

```
<script>
  jQuery(document).ready(function(){
            (function($){
                $(".keyword-search").keypress(function(){
                    var keyword = $(this).val(); 
                     $(".search-appear").empty();
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "post",
                        url: "<?php echo admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ); ?>",
                        data: { action: 'get_tour', keyword: keyword },
                        beforeSend: function() {$("#loading").fadeIn('slow');},
                        success: function(data) {
                            $("#loading").fadeOut('slow');
                            $(".search-appear").append(data);
                             }
                    });
                });
            })(jQuery);
        });
</script>
```

**And Here is my demo function:**

```
function get_tour()
            echo 'Do something!';
       ?>
      <?php  die(); }
```

And this is result when I type 3 characters:
[type 3 characters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WgfDo.jpg)
I type 2 chars:
[type 2 characters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WgfDo.jpg)
Who can help me it work 1 time no matter how many key press. Or it work fine anyway ! Thanks a lot !!

Answer (score 0):

Add your ajax to the ajaxFunction and this will work when a user types or pastes content into the search if the value is larger than 3.

The ajaxFunction will be somethign like this:

```
var ajaxFunction = function( data ) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: "<?php echo admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ); ?>",
        data: { action: 'get_tour', keyword: data },
        beforeSend: function() {$("#loading").fadeIn('slow');},
        success: function(data) {
            $("#loading").fadeOut('slow');
            $(".search-appear").append(data);
        }
    });
  }
}
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  
  var ajaxFunction = function( val ){
    $('#out').text('Val: ' + val);
  }
  
  $('#search').on('keyup paste',function(){
    if(this.value.length >= 3)
      ajaxFunction(this.value);
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="search">
<div id="out"></div>
```